# regex or any js string methods to get a text from url

Tags: javascript, reactjs, regex, string

How to get only this text

```
abc-test-bucket.s3.ap-south-1.amazonaws.com/test-Service/0022JUN_29O00190_126072.pdf
```

from this url

```
 https://s3.ap-south-1.amazonaws.com/abc-test-bucket/test-service/https%3A/%2Fabc-test-bucket.s3.ap-south-1.amazonaws.com/test-Service/0022JUN_29O00190_126072.pdf
```

Comment: Have a look in [string replace](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/replace)

Comment: There are multiple ways, you can either write a regular expression, or use the [URL](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/URL_API) Web API in combination with [String.prototype.split](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/split) to parse it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Pretty sure there are more efficient ways to do this using *regex*.

This method assumes that the last query parameter with **%** sign has 2 characters, which we remove using **substring()**

```js
const inputString = "https://s3.ap-south-1.amazonaws.com/abc-test-bucket/test-service/https%3A/%2Fabc-test-bucket.s3.ap-south-1.amazonaws.com/test-Service/0022JUN_29O00190_126072.pdf";

let subs = inputString.split("%");
let whatWeWant = subs[subs.length-1].substring(2);

console.log(whatWeWant);
```